# HTML/CSS div ordering on top of one another using z-index property

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, z-index

I am facing issue to bring the overlay panel on top of icon using HTML/CSS. I have two components as Component A and Component B.

Component A: It's header and breadcrumb design. In header section I have the down arrow, which will open overlay panel and allow the user to logout.

Component B: It's a home component, I have some graph view, in that component I have used the search icon to allow the user to search/add/edit graphs. The search icon is placed on top of the right side of breadcrumb div and bottom of overlay panel section using margin-top CSS property.

Now, the problem is for breadcrumb div i have given the z-index: 0;
In component B icon div i have given the z-index: 1001. If I am giving the z-index in less than 1001 the search icons are not visible.
In overlay panel, if i am giving z-index: 3 and component B icon div z-index: 2, it's not displaying the component B icons in the right side of breadcrumb div.

Component A:

```
Overlay Panel:

    HTML:
        <div class="layout-topbar-menu-wrapper">
            <ul class="topbar-menu fadeInDown">
                    <a>
                        <button type="button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        </button>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="fadeInDown">
                        <li role="menuitem">
                            <a>
                                <span class="textColor"><i class="material-icons textColor">exit_to_app</i>Logout</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
    CSS:
        .layout-wrapper .layout-main .layout-topbar .layout-topbar-menu-wrapper .topbar-menu>li.active-topmenuitem>ul {
            display: block;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            z-index: 3 !important;
        }
        .layout-wrapper .layout-main .layout-topbar .layout-topbar-menu-wrapper .topbar-menu>li>ul {
            position: absolute;
            top: 26px;
            right: -26.9px;
            display: none;
            width: 180px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
            -moz-animation-duration: .5s;
            animation-duration: .5s;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 8px 0;
            /* border-top: 4px solid #607D8B; */
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
            box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
        }
        .fadeInDown {
            -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 5s;
            animation: fadeInDown 5s;
        }
    
BreadCrumb Div CSS:

    HTML:
        <div class="ui-grid-col">
            <div class="layout-breadcrumb" (click)="app.onSidebarClick($event)">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span class="hyperLinkWithPointerCursorDocument">
                            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    CSS:
        body .layout-breadcrumb {
            background-color: #F4F4F4 !important;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            height: 35px;
            width: 100% !important;
            margin-left: 9.5em;
            margin-top: -2.5em;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
```

Component B:

```
Search icon Div CSS:

    HTML:
        <div>
            <span *ngIf="!isEditWidget">
              <a class="hyperLinkWithPointerCursorDocument">
                <i class="graphSearchIcon"></i>
              </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    
    CSS:
        body .graphSearchIcon {
            top: 1.8em;
            margin-right: -2em;
            z-index: 2;
            position: fixed;
            font-size: 25px !important;
            float: right;
            right: 2em;
            border-radius: 25px;
            width: 1.5em !important;
            height: 1.5em !important;
            padding: 4.2px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-top: 6px;
            color: #9d9d9d !important;
        }
```

[image]

Can anyone help me to handle this using HTML/CSS.